# How to use go-vcr with github.com/satori/go.uuid getting back Nil values for uuid

Tags: go

When I try to use go-vcr with structs containing uuid.UUID from github.com/satori/go.uuid I get back no values. Testing with other structs without uuid.UUID types works as expected.

Edit: go-vcr is a go module for recording HTTP interactions to playback: https://github.com/dnaeon/go-vcr

Testing with Ginkgo and Gomega (ommitted test code for brevity)

Go version:
go version go1.12 darwin/amd64

```
type Test2 struct {
    ID          uuid.UUID `json:"id"`
    Name        string    `json:"name"`
    Description string    `json:"description"`
}
```

```
func (s *UserService) Test2() *Test2 {
    url := fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v/test", s.ServiceHost, s.ServicePort)
    var client = &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", s.ServiceToken))
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var t Test2
    json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&t)
    return &t
}
```

Fixture:

```
---
version: 1
interactions:
- request:
    body: ""
    form: {}
    headers:
      Authorization:
      - Bearer 123abc
      Content-Type:
      - application/json
    url: http://localhost:8080/test2
    method: GET
  response:
    body: |
      {"id":"5600966e-4ad6-4f79-8e01-8db13ba5c212","name":"Foo","description":"Bar"}
    headers:
      Content-Length:
      - "79"
      Content-Type:
      - application/json
      Date:
      - Fri, 19 Apr 2019 18:49:03 GMT
    status: 200 OK
    code: 200
    duration: ""
```

Test code:

```
    us := UserService{
            ServiceHost:  "http://localhost",
            ServicePort:  8080,
            ServiceToken: "123abc",
    }
    url = fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v/test", us.ServiceHost, us.ServicePort)
    req, err = http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    Expect(err).To(BeNil())
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", us.ServiceToken))
    resp, err = client.Do(req)
    Expect(err).To(BeNil())
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    t := us.Test()
    Expect(t.Description).To(Equal("Bar"))

    r, err = recorder.New("fixtures/test2")
    Expect(err).To(BeNil())
    defer r.Stop()

    client = &http.Client{
       Transport: r,
    }

    url = fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v/test2", us.ServiceHost, us.ServicePort)        
    req, err = http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    Expect(err).To(BeNil())
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", us.ServiceToken))
    resp, err = client.Do(req)
    Expect(err).To(BeNil())
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    t2 := us.Test2()

       iDString := "5600966e-4ad6-4f79-8e01-8db13ba5c212"
    id, err := uuid.FromString(iDString)
    Expect(err).To(BeNil())
    Expect(t2.ID).To(Equal(id))
```

```
Fails with

   �[91mExpected
          <uuid.UUID>: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
      to equal
          <uuid.UUID>: [86, 0, 150, 110, 74, 214, 79, 121, 142, 1, 141, 177, 59, 165, 194,
```

Edit: Still interested in why this doesn't work, but ended up going with a different HTTP Record playback library that doesn't have this issue https://github.com/ad2games/vcr-go

Comment: What is go-vcr and what are you using it for?

Comment: @Adrian good question. Go-vcr (https://github.com/dnaeon/go-vcr) records HTTP interactions for playback. I'm using it in the context of testing a Go microservice that makes calls out to another go web server where I have a function that calls out to an endpoint test2 and expects to get back data to fill struct Test2.